# Install Ubuntu using UNetbootin without USB/CD on a separate hard disk alongside Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, windows

I have three hard disks in my computer - C (for Windows 10), E (I want to use that for Ubuntu) and D (for storing personal files).

Windows 10 is already installed. I want to install Ubuntu as well but keep Windows 10 with its files and all my data. But, I also want to install Ubuntu on a completely separate hard disk - E which is around 100GB but I want to use only 50 GB of that, though I don't really care if I can't make that restriction.
I also can't use a CD/DVD, and since this is my first time doing such a thing, may I ask for some help?

Comment: Oh, well, okay then, I guess I'm installing them on the same hard disk.

Comment: You can install Ubuntu on any disk you like. You will find the install to be fastest and easiest if you use a LiveUSB.

Comment: Would suggest using a USB stick for installer and using the 'something else' option on the installer.  Make notes of the size of your partitions and drives, because ubuntu will use different labels. ex sda3 instead of drive C.  Make sure you know which drive partition is which, check more than once.  Common mistake is for people to install over windows by mistake(very bad for data).  Should make backups of your data first.

Comment: UNetbootin has an option to install to HDD, this puts a Ubuntu installer on the hard disk. you can boot to this to install ubuntu to any other hard disk on the systen, use the something else option.

Comment: Should use the 'Try Ubuntu" option on installer first, it is for checking your hardware works well with Ubuntu and also for you to get a feel of the system before installing.

Comment: The UNetbootin hard disk install mode is temporary and can be easily removed without effecting Windows. For more information see: **Hard Disk Install Mode** https://github.com/unetbootin/unetbootin/wiki/installmodes  This option may **not** work with every release of Ubuntu. It did not work for me with Linux version of UNetbootin and the last release of Ubuntu.